# Orthogonal Decomposition => Orthogonal Complements

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Hi there can someone prove or disprove the hypothesis:
$$\left(X=U\underline{\oplus}V\right)\Rightarrow\left(U^\bot=V,V^\bot=U\right)$$
*(I don't require the space to be complete though)*

Comment: in the last line, did you inted to write $U \cap U^\bot = \{0\}$?

Comment: Also it is not clear, when you write you do not require the space to be complete, what exactly you are talking about. Do we talk about a real or complex pre Hilbert space then? Or could the field be $\mathbb{Q}$? Please make the assumptions more precise.

Comment: Oh yes sure I restrict attention to real or complex hilbert space

Comment: A Hilbert space is, by definion, complete. If completeness is not an issue you should explicitly talk about pre Hilbert space. The symbol $\bot$ is also known outside of the pre Hilbert space context, you should make clear that you are talking about an inner product space. And it's $\cap$, not $\cup$ in the last line.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant scalar a product space in my comment ...well many symbols appear in several areas however I thought it will be clear from the context ;)

Comment: But let us not struggle about these things - do you have an idea for this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's too far in the past. I'd start with something like $U^\bot$ is closed (is it? I'd have to check), so maybe $U = (U^\bot)^\bot $ and I'm done.

Comment: Yes $U^\bot$ is closed and $U^{\bot\bot}=\overline{U}$ but the point is why should $X=U\oplus U^\bot$ imply $X=U^\bot\oplus U^{\bot\bot}$?

Comment: Do u mean $\overline{A}+\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A+B}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof goes like this:
$$x\in V\Rightarrow x\bot U\Rightarrow x\in U^\bot;x\in U^\bot\Rightarrow 0=\langle x,u\rangle\stackrel{x=u+v}{=}\langle u,u\rangle\Rightarrow x\in V$$
*(analogeously for the analogue)*

Moreover, this implies: $U=U^{\bot\bot}$